# JavaScript: generated object with multiple objects inside -> one object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

this is how my object looks like:
[image: this is how my object looks like], but I need just one object like

```
obj = {
       var: "DB3,B0",
       zahl: "DB3,Int2",
       zahl2: "DB3,Int4",
       ...
       ...
      };
```

How do I convert it?
I tried different things but it all won't work inside a for loop.
I generate my Object from a string with a code like this:

```
var text = msg.payload;
var nt = text.split(" ");
var n = nt.length;
var add = [];
var name = [];
var ab = [];
var variables = {};



for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    ab[i] = nt[i].split(";");
    add[i] = ab[i][0];    
    name[i] = ab[i][1];
    variables[i] = {[name[i]] : add[i]};
}




msg.payloadvars = variables;
return msg;
```

I think it should be quite simple but I don't come to any solution.

input looks like

```
DB3,B0;var DB3,Int2;zahl DB3,Int4;zahl2 DB3,Int6;zahl3 DB3,Int8;zahl4 
DB3,Int10;zahl5 .....
```

Comment: Can you post what you are starting off with as actual code? It's hard to help you otherwise.

Comment: I read out a csv-file with a string like this
DB3,B0;var DB3,Int2;zahl DB3,Int4;zahl2 DB3,Int6;zahl3 DB3,Int8;zahl4 
DB3,Int10; ......
split it up and name the properties in the for loop..  i'll give an output example moment

Comment: Can you add some test/example input (I guess what would normally be in `msg.payload`)?

Comment: shouldn't it be : variables[name[i]] : add[i] to get the object that you desire ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let str = "DB3,B0;var DB3,Int2;zahl DB3,Int4;zahl2 DB3,Int6;zahl3 DB3,Int8;zahl4 DB3,Int10;zahl5";
let obj = str.split(" ").reduce((a,c) => {
  let v = c.split(";");
  Object.assign(a, {[v[1]]: v[0]});
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string by groups and then for value and key.

```js
var string = 'DB3,B0;var DB3,Int2;zahl DB3,Int4;zahl2 DB3,Int6;zahl3 DB3,Int8;zahl4 DB3,Int10;zahl5',
   target = Object.assign(
       ...string.split(' ').map(s => (([v, k]) => ({ [k]: v }))(s.split(';')))
    );
   
console.log(target);
```

Comment: If i write 
target = Object.assign({}, Object.values(variables)); 
I'm getting the same output like before..

Comment: please add the source object to the question, not an image of it.

Comment: Nikhil got the solution, but thank you anyways
the object code looked just like you wrote it
{
    "0": {
        "var": "DB3,B0"
    },
    "1": {
        "zahl": "DB3,Int2"
    },
    "2": {
        "zahl2": "DB3,Int4"
    },
    "3": {
        "zahl3": "DB3,Int6"
    },
    "4": {
        "zahl4": "DB3,Int8"
    },

Comment: i have no idea ... what do you have and what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make single object then you should try this:

```
var variables = {};

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    ab[i] = nt[i].split(";");
    add[i] = ab[i][0];    
    name[i] = ab[i][1];
    variables[name[i]] = add[i];
}
console.log(variables);
```